# Removing Custom Domain in Github

Tags: git, github

I am facing issue . My  gihub domin name is different and when i am going to publish it is pointing to different another domin.

http://techwithnad.me/HMTL-CSS-project - this is new pointing url

but my github username  is different

https://github.com/nadeemds/HMTL-and-CSS-Project

Answer (score 1):

Going of assumptions have you purchased the domain below

http://techwithnad.me

if you just want to see the site you can go to pages in settings or start a GitHub Actions.

Comment: i had purchased this domin but it had expired now .

Comment: I want to remove this from github

Comment: http://techwithnad.me/web-dev-bootcamp-udemy-HTML/ -> this is github site publish url

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/nadeemds/HMTL-and-CSS-Project`.

Please refer to `git help remote` or https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories for more details.

You also can edit `.git/config` and change the URLs there.

Comment: I want to remove this from github account ,  how could i do this??

Comment: http://techwithnad.me/web-dev-bootcamp-udemy-HTML/ -> this is github site publish url